# Grub showing "attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'" error when running in a proxmox VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, proxmox, scsi, grub2, virtio

After installing a Debian 11 in a proxmox VM (with packer), grub would fail to boot into the newly created VM showing the error `attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'`.
When installing a VM from the same ISO manually with default settings on proxmox, it would work fine.

When I run a rescue-session from the installer and inspect the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it is absolutely fine, as well as the file-system and partition-table.

When running `insmod normal` in the grub rescue-shell, the same error would show up again prohibiting to boot the VM "manually".

What is causing this and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't identify the root-cause but here is what caused it and what I did to fix it:

The `scsi_controller` in the proxmox-integration for packer defaults to `lsi` which seems to cause this issue.
I switched it to `virtio-scsi-single` and the disk type to `virtio` which fixed the issue for me.

This is the relevant config:

```
...
  scsi_controller         = "virtio-scsi-single"
  disks {
    disk_size             = "32G"
    type                  = "virtio"
    storage_pool          = "local-lvm"
    io_thread             = true
  }
...
```

Comment: It looks like Packer's template is hopelessly outdated. VirtIO SCSI is the default in PVE for more than five years already. I'd expect all sorts of other artifacts in it, for example default video controller setting which was changed when transitioning from PVE5 to 6 if I am not mistaken.